# What is a pancake lens?

Tags: lens, terminology, lens-design

I've read about a "pancake lens" but don't really understand what that means.

What the pros and cons of having a pancake vs. another type of lens?

I'm thinking of getting a Panasonic Lumix DMC-GF1 which comes with such a lens.

Comment: Not what you asked, but the 20mm f/1.7 Panasonic is a wonderful lens.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A pancake lens is designed to be **physically very thin and compact**, being relatively pocketable when combined with a slim body.

Current pancake lenses have a fixed focal length in the middle of the spectrum (neither wide nor telephoto), and they are relatively slow for a prime lens (often f/2.8) although exceptions exist. The image from a pancake lens looks the same as an image from a bulkier lens of the same focal length; they have no special effect.

Although the pancake design is quite old, it has been popularized lately by mirrorless systems. Currently produced pancake lenses include:

- [Canon EF-M 22mm (35e) f/2.0 STM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF-M_22mm_lens)
- [Canon EF-S 24mm (38e) f/2.8 STM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF_24mm_lens)
- [Canon EF 40mm f/2.8 STM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF_40mm_lens)
- Fuji XF 18mm (27e) f/2
- Fuji XF 27mm (40e) f/2.8
- Lomography LC-A Minitar-1 32mm f/2.8 (M mount)
- Lomography New Russar+ 20mm f/5.6 (L39, M mounts)
- Olympus M.Zuiko Digital 17mm (34e) f/2.8 (Micro Four Thirds)
- Olympus Zuiko Digital 25mm (50e) f/2.8 (Four Thirds)
- Panasonic 14mm (28e) f/2.5 Asph (Micro Four Thirds)
- Panasonic 20mm (40e) f/1.7 Asph (Micro Four Thirds)
- Pentax DA 21mm (32e) f/3.2
- Pentax DA 40mm (60e) f/2.8
- Pentax DA 70mm (105e) f/2.4
- Samsung NX 16mm (24e) f/2.4
- Samsung NS 20mm (31e) f/2.8
- Samsung NX 30mm (46e) f/2.0
- Sony E 16mm (24e) f/2.8
- Sony E 20mm (35e) f/2.8
- Voigtländer Color-Skopar 21mm f/4.0 P (M mount)
- Voigtländer Color-Skopar 25mm f/4.0 P (M mount)
- Voigtländer Color-Skopar 35mm f/2.5 PII (M mount)
- Voigtländer Ultron 40mm f/2 SL-II

Here is an example of a pancake lens:

[image: Canon EF 40mm f/2.8 STM pancake lens]

<sup>*Canon EF 40mm f/2.8 STM pancake lens*. [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Canon_EF_40mm_STM_lens_(focus_stacked_version).jpg), CC-BY-SA</sup>

Comment: They don't have to be wide to normal angle.  Don't forget the excellent Pentax DA 70mm (105e): http://www.mylensdb.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/PENTAX-DA-70mm-F2.4-Limited.jpg

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the Voigtländer's 20mm/F3.5 Color Skopar and maybe the 40mm/F2.0 Ultron can be viewed as pancakes, for FF & APS-C formats (Nikon, Canon & Pentax): http://www.voigtlander.com/cms/voigtlaender/voigtlaender_cms.nsf/id/pa_fdih7pyj95.html

Comment: A lens being "Pancake" has no direct implications about size. While all the pancake lenses on the market currently *are* compact, the *size* is **not** what makes them "pancake lenses". It is the lens's shape.

Comment: Is this answer still up-to-date or have pancake lenses changed much in the past 7 years?

Answer (score 2):

"Pancake lens" is a purely physical description.
If the lens is significantly wider than it is long, it's a pancake lens.

Actual overall size has nothing to do with it, and it has no implications about image performance, aside from the fact that it's generally very hard to pack a telephoto or fast prime into the pancake form-factor.

It's worth noting that a "Pancake lens" does **not** have to be small or compact, and a small lens is not automatically a pancake lens. It's only a description of the lens form-factor.

Comment: Interesting note; do you have any examples of non-compact pancakes? Usually there are buttons and whatnot around lens mount preventing a lens too large to be mounted. It's also optically very complicated to gain anything from a flat lens significantly wider than mount.